# Domain user still able to view view.list folder even though permission is set to Deny

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have AD on my server , I have specific user group are set to deny(List Folder) for certain folder, but the user still have visible of the folder in the server even they do not have permission to access it, what I want to archive is user without permission should not have visible of that folder. The deny(list folder) for that group of deny user is set , is that any mistake on my setting ?

Comment: Did you check "effective permissions" (under properties > security > advanced) for that user?

Answer (score 0):

I think 'Access-based Enumeration' is what you are looking for.

Check: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Access Based Enumeration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx).

Here's the explanation of the **List Folder/Read Data** permission:

*List Folder allows or denies viewing file names and subfolder names within the folder. List Folder affects the contents of that folder only and does not affect whether the folder you are setting the permission on will be listed. (Applies to folders only.)*